# Changing the Chosen multi-select item removal button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-chosen

Is there a way to adjust the button provided by the Chosen jQuery plugin used to remove selected items in a multi-select? I can obviously just override the image URL in the CSS, but that seems like a bit of a hack.

Ideally, I would like to be able to provide a different class in the options provided to the plugin, along the lines of `$('select').chosen({ multiRemoveClass: 'fa fa-remove' })`. However, that doesn't appear to be a supported feature. So what would be the best way to go about this?

Here's an example snippet that hides the button I would like to adjust:

```js
$('select').chosen()
```

```css
select {
  width: 100%;
}

/* Removes the Chosen removal button image */
.chosen-container-multi .chosen-choices li.search-choice .search-choice-close {
  background: none !important;
}
```

```html
<script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"
  integrity="sha256-CSXorXvZcTkaix6Yvo6HppcZGetbYMGWSFlBw8HfCJo="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/chosen/1.8.7/chosen.jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/chosen/1.8.7/chosen.min.css" />

<select multiple>
  <option>Option 1</option>
  <option>Option 2</option>
  <option>Option 3</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can continue on the path you've started and use pseudo-elements to accommodate your font:

```js
$('select').chosen()
```

```css
select {
  width: 100%;
}

/* Removes the Chosen removal button image */
.chosen-container-multi .chosen-choices li.search-choice .search-choice-close {
  background: none !important;
}

.chosen-container-multi .chosen-choices li.search-choice .search-choice-close:after {
  font-family: "Font Awesome 5 Brands", sans-serif; 
  content: "\f099";
  color: red;
  font-size: 12px;
}
```

```html
<script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"
  integrity="sha256-CSXorXvZcTkaix6Yvo6HppcZGetbYMGWSFlBw8HfCJo="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/chosen/1.8.7/chosen.jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/chosen/1.8.7/chosen.min.css" />

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.8.2/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-oS3vJWv+0UjzBfQzYUhtDYW+Pj2yciDJxpsK1OYPAYjqT085Qq/1cq5FLXAZQ7Ay" crossorigin="anonymous">


<select multiple>
  <option>Option 1</option>
  <option>Option 2</option>
  <option>Option 3</option>
</select>
```

Comment: That's awesome, I didn't even think about just manually setting the font family. Thanks!